# How can I make Telerik GridImageColumn follow a link on click?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, telerik

I have a Telerik `RadGrid` with several columns, where one of them in an image using the `GridImageColumn` tag. The image `src` is assigned a link pointing to a CDN location and is scaled down to fit in the `RadGrid`. When the image is clicked, I want it to open the full-size image in a new tab/window. How can I do this?

On a related note: how can I target (with jQuery or otherwise) the `img` element generated by the `GridImageColumn`? If I can just get a handle on that tag, I can add whatever handlers I need to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution after much searching and a little experimentation.

Add the following setting to the `RadGrid` element:

```
<ClientSettings>
  <ClientEvents OnRowCreated="rowCreated"></ClientEvents>
</ClientSettings>
```

This will call the `rowCreated` client function each time a row is created in the `RadGrid`.

Also, add the following client scripts:

```
function rowCreated(sender, args){
    var img = args.get_item().get_cell('Image').firstChild.onclick = imgClick;
}

function imgClick(e){
    window.open(e.srcElement.currentSrc, "name", 'width=e.srcElement.naturalWidth,height=e.srcElement.naturalHeight,resizable=1');
}
```

The parameter being passed into `get_cell()` is the value of the `UniqueName` attribute of the `telerik:GridImageColumn` that should be targeted. Using the `firstChild` of that element will target the `img` tag. Attach the appropriate onClick handler and open a new window with the handler.